# How to use Kindle through proxy?

Tags: wireless-networking, proxy, tunnel, kindle, connectify

I access internet in my college through proxy but my kindle paperwhite doesn't have any option to input proxy settings for a wifi network. How can I get it to work?

What I did to overcome the problem is that I made a wifi network using connectify and now I hope to redirect all connectify traffic through the proxy. How can I do that? I tried CCProxy and GProxy but can't get it to work. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you willing to jailbreak your kindle to do this?  If so, I can give you a solution as the kindle runs a linux distro.  Does the proxy require authentication?

Comment: Note the jailbreaking can cause Amazon to ban your device from registering, thus blocking you from accessing the kindle store on your kindle -- if you are just trying to do this in order to get books on your device, I suggest just downloading them on your computer and then loading onto your kindle with www.calibre-ebook.com

Comment: Yes, jailbreaking is fine with me. and no, proxy doesn't require authentication. I'm doing this to mainly use the wikipedia function and little browsing. And will Amazon block the device for sure?

Comment: Edited: seems like jailbreaking isn't a good solution for you.  Amazon will most likely blacklist the device, and my solution wouldn't guarantee that wiki would work anyway.  I think I have an alternative solution though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a few options to try before spending on a DD-WRT router.

1. Squid Proxy.
2. Exchange router with someone else.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a "transparent proxy", which connectify is not.  Connectify cannot pass it's traffic through a proxy, and your device can't be set to use a proxy.

***What I would do*** is to set up a router that is DD-WRT compatible (3rd party linux based firmware) and set that up as a dedicated transparent proxy.  A guide can be [found here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Squid_Transparent_Proxy), and such a router can be acquired for maybe $20-$30 and used for many many purposes.

Comment: I do have linux(ubuntu) installed, but I can't make much out of the process you told. I checked DD-WRT site. My router is TL-WR702N. on the supported router list I can find "TL-WR703N". Will DD-WRT firmware work on my router?

Comment: I deleted the crummy guide that I posted, the info is all there in the DD-WRT guide.  Your device is on the incompatible list, so no it won't work.  There are plenty of cheap units that will though, like the Rosewill RNX-N150RT on Newegg for $23 -- or perhaps you can find a buddy with a compatible router and swap with him in exchange for access to your proxied network ;)

Comment: If you have a PC host on linux with a compatible wireless card, then you could try [this](http://pritambaral.com/2012/05/connectify-for-linux-wireless-hotspot/).

Comment: @madball. That method doesn't apply to me.